# multiple time series data set with external features

Tags: r, time-series

I need a big set of time series (*multiple time series*) which is collected with some external features. How to know where I can find a good data set with these features? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. But if you need just random time.series to do some testing, you can try using BETS r addin. it links you to download many Brazilian data ts from different servers